# OpenSearch 401 for /_bulk

Tags: opensearch, fluent-bit

I am using fluent bit to stream logs from Kubernetes to OpenSearch (AWS). I have deployed via the [Helm charts](https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts) and have configured the output as below

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name opensearch
    Match *
    Host aws-domain-name.region.es.amazonaws.com
    Port 443
    Index k8s-index
    Type my_type
    tls on
    tls.verify off
    HTTP_User redacted
    HTTP_Passwd redacted
```

This gives me the following error
`[2022/09/27 11:52:19] [error] [output:opensearch:opensearch.0] HTTP status=401 URI=/_bulk`

The user has been created in OpenSearch with `all_access`. This was originally deployed using IAM roles but was replaced with HTTP username and password to try and simplify the troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was to do with the fluentbit config. The updated config is

```
 [OUTPUT]
     Name opensearch
     Match *
     Host aws-domain-name.region.es.amazonaws.com
     Port 443
     AWS_Region eu-west-1
     Index k8s-index
     TLS on
     AWS_Auth On
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenSearch uses basic authentication by default with username 'admin' and password 'admin'. Please try with this and see